# Sizing elements inside boostrap navbar for phone

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I need to expand my searchbar 'navbarSearchQuery' so that it's bigger (~280px) when the page is larger then a phone size.

And when it's a phone I want it to span across the whole top of the page when the page gets shrunk down.

Here is what I've tried and a [fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/nefvrf6j/4/).
I'm having a problem with too much space in between the search bar and the 'browse' dropdown in a size greater then a phone. And I can't seem to get the width set right on the searchbar when it's in a phone size.

```css
#navbarSearchQuery {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  width: 280px;
}
.navbar-inline {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 80%
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="navbar-inline">
        <a class="navbar-brand hidden-xs" href="/Home">Yoga</a>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" id="navbarSearchQuery" name="location">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Browse <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Popular</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Friends</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Groups</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Neighborhoods</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">About <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use media queries to adjust for it.

```css
.navbar-default #navbarSearchQuery {
  float: left;
  margin: 8px 15px 0 15px;
  width: 280px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-inline {
  display: inline;
}
@media (max-width: 360px) {
  .navbar-default #navbarSearchQuery {
    width: 180px;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-inline {
    display: inline-flex;
    width: 60%
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button>
      <div class="navbar-inline"> <a class="navbar-brand hidden-xs" href="/Home">Yoga</a>

        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" id="navbarSearchQuery" name="location">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Browse <span class="caret"></span></a>

          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Popular</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Friends</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Groups</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Neighborhoods</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">About <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a>

            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

On the same basis as the other answer of using media queries. The difference is mine has a different response on a mobile device.
http://jsfiddle.net/nefvrf6j/5/

```
#navbarSearchQuery {
   margin:8px 15px;
}
.navbar-inline {
   display: inline-flex;
   /* This makes the search bar stretch across the whole screen except 
   for the drop down menu area */
   width:calc(100% - 59px);
}
@media screen and (min-width: 360px) {
   #navbarSearchQuery {
       width:280px;
   }
}
```